# Running 'BMW Standard Tools' on Linux

Tags: linux

BMW Standard Tools is only available on Windows as far as I can find..

Does anyone know if there is an alternative way to view my error codes on my car (e9x)?

As far as I can tell I either need to:
 - use wine(not sure this will work),
 -  access my laptop from my desktops Windows OS or Visa versa, 
 - run a windows virtual machine (which I don't think will have access),
 -  use some sort of hacking/pentesting tools?

I'm really not sure how easy ir efficient any of that would be?

I'm not finding any good source material online to point me in the right direction. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The question really needs to state such things as whether you are aiming for OBD2 or EDIABAS, because that will likely affect answers.

Comment: Hmm.. I know the car uses k/D Can. I found a bunch of Can0 utils and stuff like that.. i have a feeling I'm going to end up scripting my own decoder interface. . Though there's tons of resources already out there. I really need to be able to work in EDIABAS